# Rich notification not received when app is force quit

Tags: ios, push-notification, appboy, braze

This problem is related to Appboy/Braze SDK. Atleast I hope so.

In case the app is terminated and a sample standard/simple push is sent I get the notification. However, rich notification doesn't appear at all.

This rich notification is implemented as push stories where there are more than one page and you can scroll through the notification.

When app is in foreground or background everything works fine.

Any ideas what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the APNS payload. The value of **alert** inside **aps** directory was empty string.

Also the log in the **Console** showed these two logs.

```
Received remote notification request [ hasAlertContent: 0, hasSound: 0 hasBadge: 0 hasContentAvailable: 1 hasMutableContent: 0 ]

Not delivering user visible notification because it has no alert, sound or badge
```

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH10-SW8):

> To support a background update notification, make sure that the
>   payload’s **aps** dictionary includes the **content-available** key with a
>   value of **1**. If there are user-visible updates that go along with the
>   background update, you can set the **alert**, **sound**, or **badge** keys in the
>   **aps** dictionary, as appropriate.